# Correct usage of sched_setaffinity with two parameters

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, task

I have recently found this prototype for the sched_setaffinity method:

```
extern long sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, const struct cpumask *new_mask);
```

I am attempting to use this to set the affinity of a task but it doesn't seem to be working. This is my implementation:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/cpumask.h>

int set_aff (pid_t pid, int core)
{
   static DECLARE_BITMAP(cpu_possible_bits, CONFIG_NR_CPUS);
   struct cpumask *const task_cpumask = to_cpumask(cpu_possible_bits);
   cpumask_set_cpu(core, task_cpumask);

   sched_setaffinity(pid, task_cpumask);

   return 0;
}
```

My code compiles without any errors however when I try to call this method, it breaks. Does anyone know why?

Is there a better way to do this from inside a kernel method?

Comment: You can check taskset utility source code https://gitorious.org/util-linux-ng/util-linux-ng/source/de878776623b120fc1e96568f4cd69c349ec2677:schedutils/taskset.c

Comment: what do you want to know ? why your code breaks or how to code the functionality ?

Comment: I want to know how to code the functionality as in am I instantiating something in the wrong way. The implementation I have above to set the affinity from a kernel scheduler function causes the boot up sequence of my device to stop after a certain point and restart continuously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "sched\_setaffinity()" in Linux Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013836/using-sched-setaffinity-in-linux-kernel)

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(1, &cpuset);
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset)) 
            exit(1);
```

Comment: This implementation works when I run the method from user space. I am trying to set the affinity from the kernel space. The kernel space has a different prototype for the sched_setaffinity() method which takes 2 paramenters the pid and a struct cpumask.