# Using "sched_setaffinity()" in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

Lots of posts on `sched_setaffinity`, but almost none on using this in Kernel Space.

I am on Kernel 4.14.79.

I tried using the User Space method of calling `sched_setaffinity` in the form of:

```
cpu_set_t my_set;        
CPU_ZERO(&my_set);       
CPU_SET(7, &my_set);     
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set);
```

But upon trying to compile the Kernel, I got errors and realized this form will not work in Kernel Space.

I see that `sched_affinity` is defined in `sched.h` and has the form:

```
extern long sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, const struct cpumask *new_mask);
```

But I am confused on how to correctly create the `new_mask` parameter with the correct CPU number. The documentation on it is not very helpful.

Can someone show an example of how to use this function in Kernel Space to set a process to a specific CPU?

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer myself after digging through Kernel files looking for where `cpumask` makes an appearance.

You can use these two functions:

`cpumask_clear(struct cpumask *dstp) //clear the mask you are about to use`

`cpumask_set_cpu(unsigned int cpu, struct cpumask *dstp) //set the cpu number`

So something like this is what I used:

```
struct cpumask mask;  
cpumask_clear(&mask); 
cpumask_set_cpu(cpuNumber, &mask); 
sched_setaffinity(pid, &mask);
```